# Selenium + Firefox Dev-Edition: send_keys throwing [object Undefined] exception

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

Trying to input username during login using `send_keys()` method. I guess it's able to locate the input element, as when I run until before `send_keys` it works. With sending a string value in `send_keys`, it's throwing an error.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string

What am I missing?

Python : 3.5
Selenium 3.3.1
Firefox Developer Edition or Nightly (currently version > 52)
My code snippet:

```
login_url = "https://korunet.co.nz/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(login_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#IDToken1')))

elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#IDToken1')
elem.click()
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("10101")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "D:/PycharmProjects/JCBbidEntry/tests/loop2.py", line 29, in 
>       elem.send_keys("10101")
>       File "C:\Users\BaruaR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 347, in send_keys
>       self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
>       File "C:\Users\BaruaR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 491, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>       File "C:\Users\BaruaR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>       File "C:\Users\BaruaR\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: Could you share URL or HTML Code

Comment: So I have been using Firefox developer edition(which was in my Windows path). When I use the stable version, and explicitly specify the binary via "binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')" , then it works fine.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with FF 53 beta.

Comment: Raised - https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/5601 (I would put it as a comment, but don't have 50 reputation:) )

Answer (score 4):

Appears to be resolved, at least for me with the latest version of geckodriver 0.16: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.16.0

Note that version 0.16 requires selenium 3.4.

-Erinn

Comment: I also resolved it using the version 0.16 of geckodriver and upgrading selenium. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Same here ...
Seems to be a problem with FIREFOX ... it works as expected with CHROME ;-(

Comment: It's in the unstable versions of firefox only, the release version and the older versions work fine. I donno where to file this bug though.

Comment: thanks @najjarammar - after using regular firefox everything worked out fine

Answer (score 2):

i have also same problem in my case my geckodriver is 64bit but firefox is 32 bit it throws an error

Comment: This is not an answer, you can put in comment or up vote for this question

Comment: it was a useful answer for me. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Had a Firefox update and the same happened to me. Re-installed Geckodriver 64-bit (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to geckodriver 0.17.0 fixed the issue for me
Firefox 53.0.3
Selenium 3.4.3
Python 3.6

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary) 
driver.get(url)

emailInput = driver.find_element_by_id("login-username")
emailInput.send_keys("username")
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me is to set value attribute, instead of using send_keys.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('login-username').setAttribute('value', 'username')")
```